# Problem redirecting inside of passport.authenticate()

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I am having a problem with passport js authentication. I am getting an error from trying to access a property of undefined when calling `res.redirect('/')` inside my `passport.authenticate()` callback. My authentication strategy is like this:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  session: false
}, (username, password, done) => {
  console.log('strategy invoked');
  let user = new User('jason', 'password');
  return done(null, user);
}));
```

and my route handler:

```
app.post('/auth', 
passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/fail'},
function(req, res){
    console.log('authenticate callback');
    console.log(req.body);   //logs undefined
    res.redirect('/');       //throws error here
  }
));
```

so when I use curl to make a POST to the /auth route I get an error that says: `Cannot read property &#39;redirect&#39; of undefined`. I have tried multiple variations of the route handler including ones where I just set the successRedirect to '/' but my route handler for '/' is never triggered. I have also tried this one:

```
app.post('/auth', (req, res) => {
passport.authenticate('local', (req, res) => {
    console.log('authenticate callback');
    console.log(req.body);
    res.redirect('/');
  })(req, res);
});
```

So my question is:

1. How can I access the req and res objects inside of the authentication callback in order to 
   read req body and send a response, for `example res.redirect('/');`?
2. If setting `successRedirect: '/'` is a better option how can I make sure that my redirects 
   are actually followed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in your code.  You're combing the passport middleware and the callback function into the same argument.   Try the code below or check out the example in the docs: http://www.passportjs.org/docs/downloads/html/

```
app.post('/auth', passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/fail'}), function(req, res){
    console.log('authenticate callback');
    console.log(req.body);   //logs undefined
    res.redirect('/');       //throws error here
});
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't notice that. Thanks.